# React composition events

Tags: javascript

The React docs specifies three "composition events".

```
onCompositionEnd onCompositionStart onCompositionUpdate
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#composition-events

What does composition imply and when do these events occur?

Comment: It has something to do with IME input for languages like Japanese...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those events would fire when you type non-latin characters like Japanese with IME input to "compose" a word with one or more than two letters. I made a simple demo gif below, please take a look to get a better idea.
[demo of when CompositionEvent occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D5U0.gif)

Comment: got it , thanks for example , that just removed all darkness from `CompositionEvent `. upvoting

Comment: here to solve toUppercase IME input issue on macOS/iOS
https://developpaper.com/solve-the-problem-of-using-input-method-to-input-in-the-react-input-box/

Answer (score 6):

The DOM CompositionEvent represents events that occur due to the user indirectly entering text. It is not React's own event.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent

Comment: sadly, I look at that link and get no insight when to use these, or how they are different from something like an onChange event

Comment: Apparently mostly only relevant to non-latin character typing: http://blog.evanyou.me/2014/01/03/composition-event/

Comment: Also relevant when trying to monitor key presses on an Android device. Android key events don't communicate what key is pressed.

Comment: Excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413620/4842857