# What is JavaScript's CompositionEvent? Please give examples

Tags: javascript, dom-events

[MDN is very vague about what the `CompositionEvent` means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent). There are no examples and the correlated events, such as [`compositionstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionstart), [`compositionupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionupdate) and [`compositionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionend), also have no examples and don't explain it much better.

Quoting MDN:

> The DOM CompositionEvent represents events that occur due to the user indirectly entering text.

And, for events:

> The compositionstart event is fired when the composition of a passage of text is prepared (similar to keydown for a keyboard input, but fires with special characters that require a sequence of keys and other inputs such as speech recognition or word suggestion on mobile).
>   [...]
>   Gecko fires this event **when IME starts composition**, and some platforms don't have an API for canceling composition once it's begun.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221639/4621141) states that CompositionEvents are mostly used for non-latin characters (such as when user inputs Japanese characters). I think anything that needs an IME (= input method?) can trigger these composition events. I only use latin characters, so I have never used an IME, I guess. Although IME apparently also relates to Android keyboard's composition.

*My question: What are CompositionEvents used for and when will these events be triggered? Please give concrete examples to clarify its uses*. And also: can it be used for composing unicode characters such as `ô`, `ç` and `ü`?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? How can I improve my question?

Comment: If I understood correctly, Linux seems to use `CompositionEvent` for composing some unicode characters, such as `ü`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#Dead_keycodes_for_Linux . I don't think Windows and Mac reproduce this behaviour

Comment: More info related to `CompositionEvent` and IME: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/IME_handling_guide , some information on OS handling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/IME_handling_guide#Native_IME_handlers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**CompositionEvent**

Composition Events provide a means for inputing text in a supplementary or alternate manner than by Keyboard Events, in order to allow the use of characters that might not be commonly available on keyboard. For example, Composition Events might be used to add accents to characters despite their absence from standard US keyboards, to build up logograms of many Asian languages from their base components or categories, to select word choices from a combination of key presses on a mobile device keyboard, or to convert voice commands into text using a speech recognition processor. Refer to [§5 Keyboard events and key values](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#keys) for examples on how Composition Events are used in combination with keyboard events.

Conceptually, a composition session consists of one [compositionstart](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#compositionstart) event, one or more [compositionupdate](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#compositionupdate) events, and one [compositionend](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#compositionend) event, with the value of the [data](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#dom-compositionevent-data) attribute persisting between each stage of this event chain during each session.

> **Note:** 
>   While a composition session is active, keyboard events can be dispatched to the DOM if the keyboard is the input device used with the composition session. See the [compositionstart](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#compositionstart) event details and [IME](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#keys-IME) section for relevent event ordering.

Not all [IME](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#keys-IME) systems or devices expose the necessary data to the DOM, so the active composition string (the Reading Window or candidate selection menu option) might not be available through this interface, in which case the selection MAY be represented by the [empty string](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#empty-string).

Refer: **https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-compositionevents**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CompositionUpdate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input">
    <pre id="log"></pre>
    <script>
      var input = document.getElementById('input')
        , log = document.getElementById('log')
      ;
      ['compositionstart', 'compositionupdate', 'compositionend', 'keydown']
        .forEach(function (event) {
          input.addEventListener(event, function (ev) {
            log.textContent += event + ': ' + (ev.data || ev.keyCode) + '\n';
          }, true);
        })
      ;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running the above HTML file, and composing an à on my Mac keyboard (Alt-`, a) I get the following results:

```
Gecko                         | Chromium                      | WebKit
----------------------------- | ----------------------------- | ---------------------------
`keydown`: 18                 | `keydown`: 18                 | `keydown`: 18
`keydown`: 192                | `keydown`: 229                | `compositionstart`: 0
`compositionstart`: undefined | `compositionstart`: undefined | `compositionupdate`: \`
`compositionupdate`: \`       | `compositionupdate`: \`       | `keydown`: 229
`compositionupdate`: à        | `keydown`: 229                | `compositionend`: à
`compositionend`: à           | `compositionupdate`: à        | `keydown`: 229
                              | `compositionend`: à           |
```

I'm using `keyCode` instead of `key` because WebKit. The differences between the `keydown` values are not that important. The
difference in event order, and the fact that Firefox triggers no `keydown` after composition is initiated, Chrome gives you one in the middle, and Safari throws in an extra one at the end is fun!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'm still reading the references and learning a lot from it! If I understood your answer correctly, there was a `compositionEvent` for composing the character `à` in all three browsers, am I right? But I'm on Windows and I can't trigger any composition event, whenever I try one of these funny characters (such as `à, ÿ, ô`). Am I doing something wrong? Running your code I still don't get a `compositionstart`

Comment: @flen How do you "trigger" them? You need to use multiple key strokes (not e.g. write it as a single character).

Answer (score 1):

So when I use the e.g. Japanese either by hitting one of the composition keys on my keyboard or by selecting IME Japanese from the OS language preference menu the keyboard enters a mode where multiple key strokes are combined into a single Hiragana/Kanji.

For instance to write car in Japanese, kuruma. I'd enter IME mode, (I think this is where a [compositionstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionstart) event will be triggered) and start typing 'k,u' which will be transformed to hiragana　く　and at this point the IME will list possible kanji that begin with the く　sound , this continues for 'r,u' る　etc. (I assume this is where the [compositionupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionupdate) events are triggered) until I hit space or select a kanji from the IME dropdown menu. At this point the final composed word 車 (kuruma, car) is shown an inserted into the text box and a [compositionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionend) event is fired.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Do you know whether `compositionEvent` can also be triggered for letter close to the latin alphabet, such as `ô`? I think in Linux this is possible.

Comment: @flen I think any key entered while in "IME Mode" will trigger a compositionupdate event. Then it depend on the current IME and language, what the actual data of that event will be.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a compose key by default (like Linux/Mac) so I don't think composition events will be sent unless you install a language pack with IME. (e.g. Japanese https://www.coscom.co.jp/learnjapanese801/msime_win10_en1.html) . This means as far as I know there is no consistent way to use the compose events in browsers for the purpose you are asking about.

Comment: Ah! So maybe only Linux and Mac will trigger `CompositionEvent` for accented characters! Thank you for clarifying this!