# JS - Force dead key to be printed

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, keyboard-events

I need to catch all keys when they are pressed including dead keys (e.g. ´,^) and print them. I noticed, that under normal circumstances dead key is printed only when followed by e.g. space, so it requires two inputs, "´" and " " to produce "´". Since I need to print it on the first input, I tried to fire the space manually, something like this:

```
onKey: async function (event) {

...

  if (event.key === "Dead") {
    const fakeInput = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: " ",
      view: global,
    });
  document.body.dispatchEvent(fakeInput);
  }

...

}
```

But this only produces " ", it doesn't include the dead key in it. And the dead key remains still in some queue, because if I press as next key e.g. "a", I'll get "á".

I'm listening on 'keydown' (that's why I also try to fake that) and the listening happens on the whole body:

```
document.body.onkeydown = (ev) => {
    this.onKey(ev);
};
```

So can I force the dead key out of this queue? Or is there some other way how to do it? I hope my question is clear, if not, I'll try to add more info.

Comment: On what element are you attaching the event listener? What event are you listening for? eg keyup,keydown

Comment: @Jackson I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Software for combining inputs into characters are referred to as *input method editor* (IME). It is widely utilized in many foreign languages for producing word characters, such as Japanese, where users can combine syllable characters into Kanji, Hiragana or Katakana.

This feature of keyboards of combining characters depends on the keyboard layout, which is configured on the OS level.

#### Printing 'dead' keys

From the keyboard events (`keydown`, etc.) there is little information except for the `isComposing` flag, which tells you if the users is composing a combined character.

Introducing the [Composition Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent)! It allows you to see which composition character is being typed.

#### Forcing dead keys out of the queue

From what I can tell it is not possible to remove the dead character from the keyboard input "buffer". What you could do is to filter out all characters that contain a composition characters (´, `, ^, ~, etc.) and replace them with the "normal" character. For example, filter é, ê and è and print an e instead. This solution would probably do fine for a limited amount of composition characters.

#### Sources

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#IME_and_composition_keys
- https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-compositionevents

Comment: Hi, I got back to this topic and your suggestion is unfortunately not helping me, because in Windows the composition event is not triggered, I tested it e.g. in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226598/what-is-javascripts-compositionevent-please-give-examples

Comment: I also examined your linkhttps://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#IME_and_composition_keys, where "Dead" key has description: "If you wish to identify which specific dead key was pressed (in cases where more than one exists), you can do so by examining the KeyboardEvent's associated compositionupdate event's  data property." But I did not find any way to do that :(